# Music Fan SE Proposal

Tags: discussion

The Music Fan SE proposal has been gaining traction over on Area51. I know most of this site, besides being musicians, theorists, and students, enjoys music.

Hopefully if Music Fans gets to beta we will have a mutually beneficial relationship with them including migrating questions and a common, growing user base. This is the site we have been asking for, for quite a while, as a place to send those good questions about songs/bands etc that are off topic here under the **song identification** rule, and it is likely to have questions which will be migrated here.

**http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61574/music-fans**

**Update 31 July**: It is now in commitment phase, which just means it needs more people to sign up, so keep on telling your friends, colleagues, anyone you know who likes music, etc.

**Update 25 November**: The site has been in the commitment phase for a few months now and has 127 committed users. It still needs 73 more people to commit to move into private beta.

Answer (score 4):

When I search for more Music sites proposals in Area 51, I found this:

### [Musical Instrument Design and Construction](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/65027/musical-instrument-design-and-construction)

Some of our off-topic question are belongs there. How about we support it too?

Comment: This site already allows questions about instrument maintenance, and, at least to my mind, it feels like instrument design & construction would naturally be a parallel topic to that (though highly-specialized). Just my 2¢.

Comment: What questions were off-topic here? All of the example questions look like they'd be on-topic on this site.

Comment: @NReilingh I raised that question on Area 51: http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/14720/how-is-this-different-from-musical-practice-performance

Comment: IIRC I asked about this myself a while back and was told that a more specific site would attract the experts.  Hard to say whether that is true.

Comment: Didn't make it...

Answer (score 2):

I just go down there (Area 51) again, and I found this:

### [Music Theory and Composition](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64363/music-theory-and-composition)

with low followers and questions.

**UPDATE** - this site has been closed as the scope fits entirely within Music.SE

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that one too. It's quite clear a duplication of this SE, but the very few people who signed up thinks this SE isn't academic or serious enough. That proposal will not make it unless something drastic happens. We shouldn't support it at any rate.

Comment: I saw the proposal for that site very soon after starting to use Music.SE. I could see the reasoning behind those who wanted to set it up, but totally agree that the type of information they want to share should all be available through Music.SE posts. It's a two-way-street; if academic musicians post academic questions on Music.SE, academic musicians will be more inclined to use the site to answer questions, share information and request information. Even in the short time I've been using Music.SE I've noticed that there are posts of this type, but not many; I hope this aspect grows.

Comment: In the end, the scope of Music.SE should be defined, but the *level* should be limitless. I came to Music.SE through StackOverflow - you still have questions posted there such as "What is an integer?" (by people like me!), and rightly so, some people want to know that. And that is fine, as long as questions requiring far more knowledge and expertise are also catered for. I hope we can cater for the full spectrum on Music.SE...

Comment: Stack Overflow is also an example where disjunct subjects share the same SE. E.g. many C programmers will not care that much about Java questions and so forth, so surely there should be room for a broad spectrum here too.

Comment: Has been closed as a duplicate of this site.