# Will we want to rename music.SE?

Tags: discussion, scope, site-attributes

As we all know, there is a [Music fans SE proposal](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/799/music-fan-se-proposal) going strong right now.

My question is fairly simple: soon, we may have "music" and "music-fan" as stackexchange websites. For more clarity, wouldn't we want to rename "music" to "musicians" or something similar? Right now, the names make these SEs appear as if music-fan's scope is *part of* music's scope, while this is absolutely not the case.

(Disclaimer: I do not know whether renaming a website is technically possible. I could see this causing a lot of issues with linking and whatnot.)

Answer (score 5):

Technically possible, yes, but highly inadvisable.

I would not support the renaming of this site's domain. I do [obviously support](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/a/711/133) the renaming of the site itself, but that would not affect links or the domain.

I really don't think this is our problem -- Music Fans.SE will need to think up a domain that makes sense for them. I don't think "cross-domain scope contamination" is going to be a problem.

Comment: I'd have to agree. Music Fans may get a more suitable name if it reaches beta. It would be a lot of effort to rework our site.